# Combination tags (aka "hyphenated tags")

Tags: discussion, tags, editing-help, clean-up, tag-hierarchy

Basically, I noticed that there is a tag for [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel), [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) and then [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba). The third one is just the use of VBA as it applies to Excel. As far as I can tell, there is no reason why you should ever use [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) rather than the first 2 in combination.

Obviously there are other examples of this, but these are some of the ones I found: <s>[excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba)</s>, <s>[excel-vba-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba-mac)</s>, [import-from-excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import-from-excel), [excel-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-import), [excel-charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-charts), [excel-automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-automation), [excel-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-template), [excel-external-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-external-data), [import-from-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import-from-csv), <s>[word-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-vba)</s>, <s>[word-vba-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-vba-mac)</s>, [mongodb-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-php), [mongodb-indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-indexes) and many more.

From my perspective, these combination tags are a bad thing since they create unnecessary duplication of effort, lead to inconsistency in the system and make it hard to filter questions properly.

An additional issue is that an asker may be unsure what to use and be tempted to add redundant tags to reach a wider audience. For example, if you have a question on importing a CSV file into Excel using VBA, you can use: [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel), [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba), [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba), [excel-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-import), [import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import), [file-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-import), [csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csv), [import-from-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import-from-csv), [csv-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csv-import).

**My question:**

Are tags that are purely a combination of other tags allowed and what should I do with these kinds of tags if I come across them?

Comment: Regarding the specific combination of [excel-vba], [word-vba] etc., I suggest changing [excel-vba] to [excel-object-model] or [excel-objects], which is usually the meaning in any case. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/rename-or-otherwise-replace-foo-vba-to-foo-object-model).

Comment: Added [meta-tag:tag-hierarchy] as it also includes "tag categories" (related [Add "tag categories"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24718/289691))

Answer (score 1):

Not all the tags having hyphens are "purely a combination of other tags", i.e. [sourceforge-appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourceforge-appscript) was created to solve a problem. Before that we had [sourceforge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourceforge) and [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript) that was good having both tags, but relative recently also a lot of questions about Google Apps Script  were mistagged with [appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appscript). See [Rename [appscript] → [sourceforge-appscript]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399042/1595451).

Also there might be tags that require an hyphen.

Rather than worrying about a question having a tag thats looks as the combination of other tags, look if the question have the tags that best describe it, that might help readers to better understand it and that might help people to find them as well to find the frequent tags (nowadays this might done with the help of custom filters, see [Most frequent questions for a tag combination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420727/1595451)).

If you find that a tag, having hyphens or not, is causing problems, there are several things that might be done. Please checkout the tags wikis of the following meta-tags:

- [clean-up](/questions/tagged/clean-up)
- [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request)
- [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request)
- [tag-disambiguation](/questions/tagged/tag-disambiguation)
- [blocklist-request](/questions/tagged/blocklist-request)
- [burnination-request](/questions/tagged/burnination-request)

---

More cases that led to have tags that might look as "combination tags"

- [Can we have an [excel-js] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306842/1595451)
- [Split [nx] into [nrwl-nx] and [nomachine-nx]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382809/1595451)
- [Split [mps] into [jetbrains-mps] and [pytorch-mps]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420532/1595451)

Comment: Please, do not separate request from those tags.

Comment: @Braiam What do you mean?

Answer (score -2):

This problem is equivalent to a general problem that wikis have, called "[intersection categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Category#Searching_for_pages_in_categories)".

Wiki projects that solved this problem for themselves appear to take this stance towards it:

1. An intersection category shall be used instead of its components if not all combinations of base categories can be true for a subject

   - E.g. a character from a franchise can be present in multiple works but have different roles in them
2. An intersection category shall be used instead of its components if the combination of qualities that it represents is of more interest for a subject than the separate qualities by themselves.

   - E.g. lists of defining entities (characters, locations, quests) in a specific work are definitely of a major separate interest from those covering the entire franchise. This isn't as pronounced for less important entities like items.

While 1) is objective, 2) is subjective (there do appear to be objective "tells", but I can't flesh them out at the moment).

So, **this question can only be answered on a case-by-case** (tag-by-tag?) **basis.** The last phrase is hereby the answer to this (general) question.

Comment: I couldn't find either of those quotes from wikipedia. The current stance is fully populated primary categories: [**The general rule would be: If a category can be completely and totally expressed as the intersection of other categories, it is not a primary category and should be defined only as this intersection**](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Category_intersection#Fully_populated_primary_categories). The whole page seems to send the general idea that primary categories should be fully populated, while intersection categories will be created automatically.