# Can we have an [excel-js] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

As part the the 2016 release of Office, we've vastly improved the JS API surface for both Word and Excel as shown in this [blog post](http://dev.office.com/blogs/Office-js-Public-Preview). Thus, we'd like to create [excel-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-js) and [word-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-js) tags, kind of like there is for VBA, so that we can use to track and better answer these questions. However, since there already is a [exceljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exceljs) tag for a NodeJS Excel library, I'm unable to create a [excel-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-js) tag and need Meta's approval.

There are already questions that I think these new tags would apply to.  For example, I'm trying to tag [Chaining Promises in Office.js with Excel.run()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32786589), but can't.

What do you think? Should there be an [excel-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-js) tag?

Comment: I'm trying to add the tag to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786589/chaining-promises-in-office-js-with-excel-run/32788392#32788392). I have the necessary reputation and all, but as I said in the question, there is a tag with a similar name that already exists, thus preventing me from creating that tag.

Comment: @rene Technically, just related- The answer there does suggest a meta question to discuss the tag creation, and the way the question is worded _does_ invite discussion.

Comment: Sorry, just realized the mistagging. Corrected it.

Comment: IIRC there was a big discussion *against* the [office-vba] tags a little while ago. I imagine the answer to this will depend on the resolution of that. The discussion is here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/synonymize-very-bad-amalgam-tags-excel-vba-access-vba-word-vba-powerp

Comment: Do you think it would be reasonable to create it now and depending on the resolution of that other discussion, modify/get rid of it?

Comment: I think it would be very valuable to have this tag.  Right now, many questions about the "apps for Office" model end up tagged just as "office365" or "ms-office", which is a *huge* pool of questions on anything from PowerPoint to Access, and from VBA to VSTO to Excel Add-ins to COM automation, etc.  Being able to have a precise tag for Excel JavaScript APIs would both make it easier for folks in the community to find questions and help each other, and also give a single tag that the extensibility team responsible for the new APIs can watch and respond to.

Comment: I edited your question to point out that there are already questions where the tag you're suggesting would be appropriate.  Don't suggest creating a tag ahead of time, suggest tagging things that need tagging once they exist.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky How about [tag:office-js] then?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, Having "office-js" might be a good tag to have too, as an "umbrella" tag -- but I still think there's value in a tag specific to Excel and Word. The scenarios (and, consequently, the object models) between the tow are different enough that folks who have expertise with one might have little expertise with the other. That is, if the goal of the tag is to reduce signal-to-noise ratio, I would argue that "excel-js" and "word-js" would do a better job than a single "office-js" tag (though again, not at all opposed to having it as an uber-tag). Does that make sense?

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky I think the question is (and this is also posed in the linked discussion) would it better by served by [tag:excel-js] or a combination of [tag:office-js] and [tag:excel]. I *suspect* it would be the latter, though I have no empirical data to back that up.

Comment: You can manipulate Word and Excel documents from **JavaScript** now? *You were so preoccupied with whether or not you could, that you didn't stop to think if you should.*

Comment: @IanKemp, indeed you can. And if you don't know about it, then don't question if it's useful, because you don't know what it's (and you are talking) about.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks @PatrickHofman and @BradleyDotNET!  The more I've thought about it, the more the suggestion of the double-tag made sense, so "office-js" + "excel" makes sense to me. Let's go ahead and give that a whirl!

Comment: @teylyn - I think IanKemp was just quoting a famous Jurassic Park line, rather than being serious!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just created the [office-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-js) tag since that is the least ambiguous and probably longest living option. If we include product names in it, and Microsoft changes them (just as they did with the old *apps for Office* name) we will have problems tagging them.

I would recommend to tag both [office-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-js) and [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel). That makes the question clear. No need for separate [office-excel-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-excel-js), [office-word-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-word-js), etc.

It might also be good to unambiguate the current [exceljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exceljs) or edit its tag wiki to prevent mistags.

Comment: Does this mean that with regard to excel-vba you are in the camp that advocates using an excel tag and the vba tag?

Comment: Does it matter? I think I am in that camp, yes. Although I didn't really read in on that. The [tag:office-js] was helpful anyway.

Comment: Yeah, it does somewhat matter but I rather wait and see how these tag develops. Adding  a specific tag later is always on option

Comment: Indeed. Adding this tag was useful in my opinion. I am not sure about too specific tags (which I find often useless). That's why I didn't create other tags.