# Split [mps] into [jetbrains-mps] and [pytorch-mps]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

When searching [mps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mps) tag, the tag info is speaking about [JetBrains MPS](https://www.jetbrains.com/mps/). However, there are questions about [PyTorch MPS](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/wiki/MPS-Backend) (which looks like using [Apple silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon)'s [Metal Performance Shaders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_(API)#Metal_Performance_Shaders) for speeding up machine learning), like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73266895/9035237) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72681606/9035237).

Is it necessary to split them as two tags?

<sub>There are even some questions about [IBM ILOG CPLEX's MPS file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPS_(format)), like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72618041/9035237).</sub>

Answer (score 8):

There's only two questions tagged [mps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mps) and [pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch), thus this doesn't seem to be that big of a problem. Renaming [mps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mps) is therefore not necessary. Creating a [pytorch-mps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch-mps) could be done, but I'll leave that to a subject matter expert, given the low amount of questions.

Answer (score 8):

Currently, the description of the [mps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mps) tag is as follows:

> JetBrains MPS is a language workbench to create Domain Specific Languages (DSL).

I agree with [Adriaan's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420547), but I feel we should clear up the ambiguity. To do this, I think that we should remove the [mps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mps) tag from the two questions that refer to PyTorch MPS. I don't know much about PyTorch MPS, but think the only two affected questions won't lose much from having the [mps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mps) tag removed. Those two questions already fall under [pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch), so it's not like these will become questions without any descriptive or widely watched tags.

If the [mps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mps) tag is allowed to continue referring to either JetBrains MPS or PyTorch MPS, then it can only add ambiguity to the vast majority of questions about JetBrains MPS. The description of the [mps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mps) tag already states that it is for JetBrains MPS anyway, not PyTorch MPS.